# Updating UITableViewCell subview constraints on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` with 3 cells, which will eventually serve as a dashboard. I am trying to configure the top cell with a circular progress view using `KDCircularProgress` - I have a `UIView` which I position with constraints, and then programmatically add the circular progress object.

However, when I rotate the device to landscape, the progress view shifts (see first image). I have tried various combinations of `setNeedsLayout()`, `layoutSubviews` and `layoutIfNeeded()` but no luck.

I also tried `reloadData()` in `willAnimateRotation(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval)`, which gets me slightly further in that the view is correctly resized (see second image), however it has created a duplicate. Extract from `cellForRowAt` method below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let topCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath) as! DashboardTopTableViewCell

        //Progress config
        topCell.progressBar = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: topCell.circularProgressContainer.frame.width, height: topCell.circularProgressContainer.frame.height)))
        let colorForProgress: UIColor = UIColor(red: 69.0/255.0, green: 110.0/255.0, blue: 178.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
        topCell.progressBar?.progressColors = [colorForProgress]
        let progressAsAngle = ((percentageComplete/100)*360)
        topCell.progressBar?.animate(toAngle: progressAsAngle, duration: 2.0, completion: nil)
        topCell.circularProgressContainer.addSubview(topCell.progressBar!)

        return topCell
```

So I am a bit stuck - any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using addSubview in cellForRow. As the cell is reused, this extra added view will not get removed and on reloading cell, the views would be overlapped. You will not see the impact when overlapping is of same size and position, but as in your case you are rotating, you are able to see it. Add the views statically in XIb or view wherever you want but not in cellForRowAt.

However you can change the properties of the subviews in cellForRow.

If you add subviews in cellForRowAt you will feel the jerk while scrolling tableView.

Comment: Ah ok, understood. When you say add views in 'view wherever', which method do you have in mind?

Comment: I guess you would be having DashboardTopTableViewCell as prototype cell in Storyboard or XIB,  you can add there.

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned KDCircularProgress doesn't have a Storyboard object, hence why I'm creating it programatically.

Comment: It need not be. In your cell Storyboard, add a UIView, give its class to be KDCircularProgress and attach this to progressBar of your cell.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help